# How long does it take for a proprietary software to get reviewed to Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, application-development, application-submission

My application is just a .py file that has a GUI. I tarred it and uploaded it to Myapps under proprietary license ($0.0) as I have no idea about packaging. The source code is available at [Github](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness). It is actually open source and link to the source code would be in the about menu of the app.
 I want to know how long should it take to get reviewed.

Comment: This varies. I've seen apps reviewed within few days, but my app took more than a year to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is approved in just 5 days. However it varies from app to app. My app only had a small .py file so it took so less time.

Comment: There is'nt such fixed duration . It varies with type of app and time of reviewers